# Laravel Passing Multiple Variables to View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Learning through some videos for Laravel but hit an issue i cant seem to figure out.

I have a route

```
Route::get('/post/{id}/{name}/{password}', 'PostController@showPost');
```

A custom controller called PostController.php

```
public function showPost($id, $name, $password) {
        return view('post', compact('id','name','password'));
    }
```

and the view called post.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Post {{$id}} {{$name}} {{$password}}</h1>
</div>
```

when running the url

```
http://127.0.0.1/post/1/2/3
```

I get back a 404 page.

Comment: What happens if you put `dd($id, $name, $password);` as the first line in your `showPost` function?

Comment: I bet something's wrong with web server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to allow `.htaccess` files. The problem is your routes aren't working.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles

Comment: thanks, did that. i thought it was normally on by default, never had issues with it before.